# What was "it" referring to in the line "it was saying"?

Tags: existenz

In sci-fi movie *Existenz (1999)*, After both returning to home from video game world, Allegra found Ted's bio port is infected.

> Allegra: It's Kiri Vinokur. That bastard.
>
> Ted: Vinokur?
>
> Allegra: He gave you a new bio-port. He gave you an infected one so
>   that my pod and my game system would die!
>
> Ted: I'm infected? Wait a minute.
>
> Allegra: **It was saying it was sick by introducing the theme of disease
>   in the game.**
>
> Ted: "The theme of disease"? l'm fucking really infected!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Allegra is referring to the game system itself. It's infected and hence the game contains imagery about disease that wasn't originally programmed into it.

The conversation in the film's novelisation is worded slightly differently and makes it abundantly clear what the object in the sentence is.

> “There was no reality bleed-through after all,” Geller said. “We were thinking about it from the wrong direction. When we were in the game, **the poor thing was trying to tell us that it was sick. It was the pod that introduced the theme of disease into the game.”**
>
> “The theme of disease?”